# How to add a plus minus sign (ALT 241 or Alt 0177) ? in a vb.net label.text

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a plus minus symbol to a label in my desktop vb.net application. I found a posting that said ALT 241 or ALT 0177 were what is needed but I can't find the syntax to write the code. My guess which is wrong would be Label2.Text = "Some words " & ALT(241). I am sure this is simple but I can't find the required syntax.

Comment: "ALT 241 or ALT 0177" means: press and hold down the Alt Key then on the numeric keypad enter the given number (i.e.241). Then release the Alt key. Yields:  ±

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Label2.Text = "Some words " & Chr(177)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use (the newish) string interpolation to save a few characters of typing and improve readability:

```
Label2.Text = $"The answer is 42 {Chr(177)} 1."
```

Comment: @jmcilhinney Correct. Typo. Fixed. Thx.

Comment: I think the OP wants to print a ± symbol, so `ChrW(117)` or the fancier `ChrW(&HB1)`. `241` only with the alternate charset: numeric keypad `ALT+241`. Same as `ALT+0177`.

Comment: @Jimi Ok, I've reverted back to the original idea.

Answer (score 0):

Uou can put the character right in the string literal:

```
Label2.Text = "Some words ±"
```

It works on .Net fiddle:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/AGSQMO

Copy/paste from my answer if you need help just putting in the character.